# (jQuery) Nivo Slider error loading slides - it just loads the first image and stays like that

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I was developing a WordPress theme (for a site redesign) locally. I used and set up the jQuery version of the Nivo Slider and all was working perfectly. But once I moved the site to the server it just stopped working. The first slide loads and just stays like that. And the bullets don't load at all.
I just don't understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone help?

The website is live if somebody wants to look at the code. The URL is [www.media-soft.info](http://www.media-soft.info)

Comment: If you look at the console in firebug in your page the nivo script seems to be spitting some errors. Try including the dev version (unminified) of the script in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or in Chrome or Safari or IE8, use the developer tools to see what JS is loading on your site and the three errors you have right now with `tvjava.js` and `jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js`

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function` errors are usually jquery no conflict mode errors.

See [Using jQuery with Other Libraries - jQuery JavaScript Library](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) and [Function Reference/wp enqueue script « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) on how to correctly include javascript libraies in a WP theme without conflicts and dupocation.